# RISC-V how to use each lb, sa, li and how to properly use its syntax

Tags: string, indexing, syntax, character-encoding, riscv

I don't know how to access each character and know which one I'm accessing. In terms of the `c language`, they use char array for strings and use indexes to know which is being accessed. What is the equivalent of this in risc-v?

Answer (score 1):

- ***C has logical variables — assembly language has physical storage.***

  (Logical) variables have names & types & scope/lifetime, and hold values at runtime.  In assembly, we have physical storage: registers & memory — physical storage has size, but names are often not implemented except in comments (and for globals), while types are implemented by individual instructions of the machine code program (and by storage directives in assembly), and variable lifetimes are implemented by repurposing of physical storage as per the machine code program.

  Compilers and assembly language programmers map logical variables of our algorithms onto available physical storage.
- ***C has arrays — assembly language has arrays.***

  Arrays are consecutive storage locations, whether consecutive bytes as in a string, or consecutive words as in an array of integers/words.  An array has a base address: the address of its lowest element (e.g. at index position 0).

  In some sense, we can refer to the whole array by that base address, though usually that would be paired with a length indication of some kind, either a terminal value as in C-style string, which are nul-terminated, or an explicit length variable or constant as commonly done with arrays of integer.
- ***C has indexes — assembly language has indexes.***

  Indexes are just simple integers.  With regard to arrays, indexes usually start at zero, and increment by 1 to refer to the next element / index position, for example, no matter the size of the elements.
- ***C has pointers — assembly language has pointers.***

  In C we have the concept of pointers.  A pointer variable holds a memory address — an address in assembly language is just an (unsigned) integer.   In C, pointers have types, so they know what type of element they are pointing to.  In assembly language, pointers are just (unsigned) integers, so the program must know what they are pointing to.

  The simplest pointer in usage is as an immutable variable, e.g. simple a copy of the base address of the array.

  Pointers can be dereferenced, in C and assembly.  We can dereference for read or for write.  In C a dereference is written with `*` as in `*p`, or `p[0]`, which is equivalent.  If that appears as the left hand side operand of an assignment operator (e.g. `*p = ...`), that is a dereference for write.  In assembly language we would use `sb` or `sw` for that operation.  If that `*p` appears in any other context (e.g. `c = *p`), that is a dereference for read; assembly language would use `lb`  and `lw` instruction for that operation.

  A function that takes an array as a parameter would see such a pointer.
- ***C has array & pointer indexing — assembly language has pointer indexing.***

  In C we can write `str[i]` or `arr[i]` and this will access the `i`th element of the string or integer array.

  A single integer/word, alone, stored in memory occupies 4 bytes.  As we refer to an array by its base address (the lowest address in the array), we also refer to a multi-byte value, like an integer/word, by the lowest address in that word.

  In C, `arr[i]` can be written as `*(arr+i)` *(or `*(a+(i))` if `i` represents an expression)* and, by definition of the C language, these are equivalent.  The `+` in the expanded form (not visible in the `arr[i]` form) is called pointer arithmetic.

  Further, hidden from the view in C but visible in assembly language, the assembly programmer and the processor deals with a byte addressable memory, meaning that each address refers to one byte and multi-byte items occupy not only multiple bytes but therefore also multiple addresses.  The assembly programmer & processor will also deal with byte offsets, which are scaled indexes — these offsets are not seen in C as that language sticks to indexes and pointers.

  In assembly & machine code, indexing, as in `arr[i]`, involves scaling by the element size.  For an integer array, the element at index position 0 has the same address as the base address of the array, let's say `0x1000`.  Since an integer/word takes 4 individual bytes, then, the element at index position 1 has address `0x1004`, and the element at position `i` has address `0x1000 + i * 4`.  This scaling is explicitly done in assembly language.

  The scale factor for an array of bytes (as in `str[i]`) is 1, meaning no scaling of the index is really needed: index & byte offset are equal in value.

  In RISC V assembly language, array index is done instead as pointer indexing, so with two steps, first: create a pointer variable (in a CPU register) that refers to the base address of the array, then perform pointer indexing.

  In RISC V, there is only one addressing mode, base + displacement, where base is a register containing a pointer value, and displacement is a compile time constant.  This can accomplish constant array element access: if the base array address is in register `s0`, then 0(s0) represents the addressing mode to access element 0 of the array (this can be used with an `lb`, `lw`, `sb`, or `sw` instruction).  If it is an array of bytes, then `1(s0)` represents `str[1]`, while if it is an array of integers/words, then `4(s0)` represents `arr[1]`.

  To do indexing with a variable, as in `str[i]` or `arr[i]`, we need to form a new pointer that refers directly to the memory address of the `i`th element position, then we can use RISC V's standard base + displacement where the displacement is simply 0, since the base we will use will have already computed the complete address.  For `str[i]`, form a new pointer value computed as base address of array plus the value of `i`.  For `arr[i]`, form a new pointer value computed by base address of the array plus the value of `i` appropriately scaled, e.g. multiplied by 4 or more commonly shifted left by 2.
- **C has mutable pointer variables — assembly language has them, too.***

  More advances usages of pointers involve updating them to refer to a next (or some other) element of the array.  When used like that a pointer is logically equivalent to a base array address + an index combined into one variable.  Pointer addition: adding to the pointer advances it to refer to subsequent elements, subtraction (of index/offset) moves it backwards, and subtracting a pointer from a pointer yields an index in C (and offset in assembly).

  In C we can advance a pointer, for example, modify the pointer variable to point to the next element, as in `p++`, which might also be written as `p += 1`, or `p = p + 1` — all equivalent by the definition of the C language.  This can also be done in assembly language, as long as we are also aware of the scaling, so if the pointer refers to a byte then incrementing by value 1 makes it refer to the next byte, where as for integers/words, we must increment by 4 to accomplish what is just `+1` in C.

---

Many algorithms (language independent) involve pointers.  When taking an algorithm from C to assembly language, try to stay true to the C code rather than performing optimization during translation.

If you have an array version of an algorithm and want to optimize it to use pointers in assembly, then do that in C first, and make sure it works there by testing it, then take that pointer version to assembly most literally, and you won't have algorithmic problems to debug in assembly language.

---

`la` is used in some environments like RARS, to put the address of a (usually data) label into a register.  For example, taking the address of an array and putting into an array, e.g. as a pointer.

`li` is used to put a constant integer value into a register.

There is no `sa` I'm aware of.

`lb` instructs the processor to use the (only available) addressing mode, base + displacement, to access the byte-sized memory item at the effective address and retrieve a copy of that value into a CPU register.  (The effective address is the address computed by adding the base register to the displacement.)

`lw` does the same but instructions the processor to fetch a multi-byte item that starts at the effective address.

Comment: Would be good to mention that the conversion from C indexing by element to asm indexing by bytes involves multiplying by `sizeof(T)`.  Like `&arr[idx] == (char*)arr + idx * sizeof(arr[0])`.

Comment: @PeterCordes, yes!  I'd buried scaling in there somewhere, but your highlight is the general rule.